# Move position in smooth gradient

Tags: algorithm, curve

I am decrementing/incrementing position x until it reaches y. However, this creates a rectangular-like path. I want position x to smoothly curve towards y (diagonally) on a 2D plane.

What kind of maths would I need to achieve this? 
Example image attached.

[image: Algorithm]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The math you need is linear interpolation. I think of a player sprite which moves from position X to position Y. Pseudocode:

```
playerSprite.x = Y.x + t * (X.x - Y.x)
playerSprite.y = Y.y + t * (X.y - Y.y)
```

where t is a value between 0.0 and 1.0 (floating point). Instead of incrementing the position components of Y you increment t till it reaches 1. When it reaches 1 the playerSprite reached point X. If t is 0, then the playerSprite is at position Y.

Comment: Thanks, works great! I'm still not quite understand the purpose of the float. Is it possible to have the object's speed static?

Comment: yes, the part (X.x - Y.x) is the first component of the direction vector. If you normalize it, you could multiply it with your speed and delta time. Regarding a former question that you posted on stackexchange, you should gather more information on linear algebra. See [this](http://blog.wolfire.com/2009/07/linear-algebra-for-game-developers-part-1/) for example.

Answer (score 5):

What you want is linear interpolation like @Tim points out. However he uses a formula that is not so easily understandable form, we can refactor it differently. Basically linear interpolation is a weighted average where the weight of the first term is in range of *0-1* and the weight of the other value is *1-weight*. Literature usually uses t for the weight and y for input (y can be a scalar, vector, matrix or mostly any construct). A more understandable version of the formula in scientific form is:

$$
y = t \cdot y_1 + (1-t) \cdot y_0     \quad \quad t \in [0,1]
$$

As code it looks like:

```
playerSprite.x = t * Y.x + (1-t) * X.x 
playerSprite.y = t * Y.y + (1-t) * X.y
```

There is a simple visual interpretation of this:

[image]

**Image 1**: Visual interpretation of weights (below) and the sum of vectors and position on line (above)